# Modifying Response Headers in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to modify the response headers in a Chrome extension with the following code:

```
var modifyResponse = function(details) {
    var responseHeaders = [];

    responseHeaders.push({name: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true"});
    responseHeaders.push({name: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*"});
    responseHeaders.push({name: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "OPTIONS, GET, POST"});
    responseHeaders.push({name: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control"});

    details.responseHeaders = details.responseHeaders.concat(responseHeaders);
    return {responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders};
};

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(modifyResponse, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["responseHeaders", "blocking"]);
```

In my `manifest.json` file I have:

```
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
],
```

However when inspecting the response headers in Chrome's inspector, these headers do not show up. I can confirm the `modifyReponse` method is being called, but I cannot confirm the headers are showing up. Am I missing a permission or is my code otherwise wrong or is this a limitation of extensions?

**Update:**
By running a test AJAX call on `http://api.jquery.com/` with:

```
$.get("http://api.jquery.com/", {}, function(data, status, jqXHR) { console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders()); });
```

I get the proper response headers back, which would indicate that the headers are inserted, however they still do not show up in the request inspector.

Comment: Modifications by web request API are not reflected in devtools.

Comment: @方觉 My test did confirm that, however it is a bit confusing because headers inserted via `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders` will properly show up in the inspector.

Comment: There's a bug for this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=258064.

Comment: @方觉 Feel free to submit that as the answer and I'll accept.