# Modify headers on onHeadersReceived

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

In my chrome extension I need to add a line to header of every site browsed. In background.js file I add such code:

```
var responseListener = function(details){
    var rule = {
        "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value": "*"
    };
    details.responseHeaders.push(rule);
    return {responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders};
};

 chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(responseListener,
     {urls: [   "*://*/*" ] },
     ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);
```

While debugging the handler is called and newly added header successfully passes any filters I have found upper in the stack. But it is not seen on network tab's Response headers section and does not effects any code. I use these permissions:

```
"tabs","<all_urls>", "http://*/*" ,"webRequest","webRequestBlocking", "webNavigation"
```

Is there a new policy or API changed which disallow to do such things or there is some bug in my 10 lines of a code?

Comment: Have you tried another header? Also, notice this in the docs: _"only one extension may modify `responseHeaders` for each request"_

Comment: Yes, I turnd off other ones and tried to add headers with different names

Comment: Did other headers you tried work?

Comment: Try to run `chrome.webRequest.handlerBehaviorChanged();` after registering the listener.

Comment: @Xan, no they did not too. I event tried to modify existed onces and remove some of them, it does not work also.  I added ` chrome.webRequest.handlerBehaviorChanged();` but this have not changed anythingt(the handler is called but does not effect any)

Comment: The devtools does not show any modifications by extensions. See https://crbug.com/258064

Comment: Also asked (and answered in the comments) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102082/modifying-response-headers-in-chrome

Comment: @RobW, i may post it like an answer

Comment: @FLCL Sure, go ahead.

Comment: @RobW, LOL, I mean YOU, sorry) I have some bugs in my language

Comment: @FLCL Perhaps you should reword the title to reflect the actual problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Network tab of the Chrome Developer tools does not show the modifications from extensions. See https://crbug.com/258064

If you wish to see whether your extension has successfully modified a request, visit `chrome://net-internals/#events`, click on a request of type `URL_REQUEST` and look for `URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE` entries, e.g. `URL_REQUEST_FAKE_RESPONSE_HEADERS_CREATED` (this is an example of a log entry generated via the [`chrome.declarativeWebRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest) API) or `"delegate_info = "extension [extension name]"` (generated by [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)).

Comment: Thanks for sharing so usefull knowlage!

Comment: Firefox also doesn’t show modified headers in their developer tools.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1376950