# Modify Response Header with Chrome - nosniff

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to add the attribute `X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff` to my HTTP response. 
But I can't add this attribute, just modify if it exists. ([www.google.de](http://www.google.de) for example)

I used Chrome and tried several plugins like `HeadersModify`, `ModHeader` or `Requestly: Redirect Url, Modify Headers`.

Sven

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/27130261/5995040

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you are seeing a Chrome developer [tools bug/limitation](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=258064):-

> Any modification in response headers is not visible in Chrome developer tools

In Requestly, You can setup a header rule like this:

[image]

In Requestly, you can also apply this rule to selective requests. I have left the field empty which applies the rule to all requests. Please modify it according to your use case.

Feel free to reach out to [requestly.extension@gmail.com](http://mailto:requestly.extension@gmail.com) for any issues.